# formatting path string in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, path, format

If you feel that you have to down-vote this question I would be grateful that would comment on it: any feedback is better that no feedback.

---

I have been trying to format an array of mixed path (unix and windows format) and to remove the root directory in certain case.

But I am wondering if someone could suggest something:

- either that makes use of existing function from Nodejs
- or that would be more efficient/succint.

source code:

```
var js = [
  "scripts/content.js",
  "dist/styles/styles.css",
  "dist\\vendor\\scripts\\bootstrap.min.js",
  "dist\\vendor\\scripts\\jquery.min.js"
];

var root = 'dist';

var convertPath = function(path) {
    return path.replace(/\\/g,"/");
};

var splitted = function(path) {
    return path.split('/');
};

var pop = function(arr) {
    var l = arr.length;
    if( arr[0] === root ){
      return arr.splice(1,l-1);
    }
    return arr;
};

var merge = function(arr) {
    return arr.join('/');
};

var length = js.length;
var i = 0;

for(i;i < length; i++){
    console.log(js[i] + ' => ' + merge(pop(splitted(convertPath(js[i])))));
}
```

desired output:

```
"scripts/content.js => scripts/content.js"
"dist/styles/styles.css => styles/styles.css"
"dist\vendor\scripts\bootstrap.min.js => vendor/scripts/bootstrap.min.js"
"dist\vendor\scripts\jquery.min.js => vendor/scripts/jquery.min.js"
```

[JSBin preview](http://jsbin.com/mowikejodu/6/edit?js,console)

My aim is to automate the [installation of bower components with gulp](https://gist.github.com/thoroc/2081f9987ba8426d710c) for a chrome extension project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var output = js.map(function(i){return i + " => " + i.replace(/\\/g, '/').replace(/^dist\//,'');});
```

Comment: It does not fit this: `"dist\vendor\scripts\bootstrap.min.js => vendor/scripts/bootstrap.min.js"`

Comment: And if I am going to install package `example_dist`? With path: `dist/example_dist/styles.css`

Comment: If so, you can use `.replace(/^dist\//,'');})` instead of `.replace('dist/','')`. I made the change accordingly.

Comment: I was totally unaware of the [.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function.